# How to solve Jenkins This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect Error?

Tags: java, windows, jenkins

I have got **This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect Error on the browser** in the first run of Jenkins after the installation.So I have tried to solve this issue so many times by re installing Jenkins. But unfortunately non of the attempts didn't success.By going through the Resource Monitor --> Network --> Listening Ports on Windows 10 , I have noticed that Jenkins even doesn't run on the configured port as a service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that Jenkins doesn't support to some newer java versions.So at that time I have been using the JDK 15 .So finally I have solved the issue by downgrading the JDK 15 to JDK 8u211 and reinstalling the Jenkins.